# LiveUSB Desktop doesn't load on an Inspiron B130

Tags: 11.10, live-usb, inspiron

I recently downloaded Ubuntu 11.10 and set up a Live USB, and I'm trying to get it to work on this set of hardware:

- Dell Inspiron B130
- 512 MB RAM
- 40 GB HDD
- Intel Celeron M Processor

I'm currently using the Live USB with no known issues on my Dell XPS Studio 16(Core2Duo 2.66, 4GB Ram) so I'm fairly confident it's not the USB or a corrupted ISO. When I run the USB on the Inspiron, it loads to the USB boot screen, and if I tell it to run Ubuntu from the USB it loads and goes to the desktop, however I have no icons or sidebar/topbar. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

For a single-core CPU at speeds lower than 2.0GHz, I would recommend going for [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/), which is even more lightweight than Xubuntu as offered by Mark Rooney, but for an installation, minimal install or alternate install (which are not the same), may be your best option since your RAM is not very big.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that your hardware for the Dell B130 does not support Unity and that is why it does not load - it should however run the Unity 2D but I'm uncertain as to why it does not default to that desktop on the live USB.

If you want to run Ubuntu on it I recommend either [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) or a [minimal install](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation#Minimal_installations) image and install a desktop environment your comfortable with.