# BIOS won't see neither USB nor HDD after install

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, hard-drive

I recently installed a new hard drive on a Dell Inspiron 14z laptop

I installed Ubuntu over Wifi through a mini live boot from a USB key
Absolutely no errors during these processes occured.

Since then though, the BIOS won't boot neither on the usb-key, nor the hard-drive, where the Ubuntu was installed. They are well-connected, as the diagnostics DELL utility can see both of them. There is a USB-key boot option, but when selected it fails (Stating there is nothing to boot on). The hard drive doesn't even appear, neither does grub, in the boot options.

I haven't modified the hard drive or the usb-key since the install.

If somebody has an idea as to make the computer bootable again, that would be great, I really need this laptop to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LiveUSB Desktop doesn't load on an Inspiron B130](http://askubuntu.com/questions/97395/liveusb-desktop-doesnt-load-on-an-inspiron-b130)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend rebuilding the LiveUSB with Ubuntu's Disk Image Creator from a LiveCD. It sounds like you have a corrupt boot file on the USB.

That's the most help I can offer as the question is a little unclear.

It almost sounds like your boot file is corrupt on the main drive. It that case, definitely rerun the installation and set the bootloader to install to the `/` of the hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by rewriting the ISO to usb key AND allowing bios to boot "Legacy" option.